# Internal piping with awk

Tags: awk

Let say i have input line:

input:

```
{x:y} abc det uyt llu
```

how to process it, to get expected output:

output:

```
{x:y} abc%det%uyt%llu
```

Question is how to concatanate fields 2-end of line, and in that string change space with %
where separator is space

I need fixed first part {x:y} and implementing pipe for fields 2-end of line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
s='{x:y} abc det uyt llu'
awk '{printf "%s%s", $1, OFS; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i==NF)?RS:"%"}' <<< "$s"
{x:y} abc%det%uyt%llu
```

Another awk:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s", $1, OFS; OFS="%"; $1=""; print substr($0, 2)}' <<< "$s"
{x:y} abc%det%uyt%llu
```

Comment: Second is more understandable :) @anubhava, Tnx

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `awk`

```
awk '{$1=$1;sub(/%/," ")}1' OFS="%" file
```

```
echo '{x:y} abc det uyt llu' | awk '{$1=$1;sub(/%/," ")}1' OFS="%"
{x:y} abc%det%uyt%llu
```

This change all space to `%`, using `OFS` and `$1=$1`, then change the first  `%` to space.

Comment: +1 or the right approach but IMHO `awk -v OFS='%' '{$1=$1;sub(OFS,FS)}1' file` would be preferable so you aren't hard-coding the OFS twice, aren't hard-coding a duplicate of the default FS value, and are setting the OFS variable visually before it's used.